# How To Add Analysis Graph in CDE Dashboard in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I made Some Graph in Pentaho Analysis Report and Than i Made New Dashboard in CDE Now i Want to add these Analysis Graph in CDE Dashboard is it possible or i have to made new Graph ?

I am new in Pentaho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am expecting that you want to include jpivot or saiku analytics report into dashboard.
Do the following steps for creating data-source connection.

- once you create new CDE Dashboard. select datasource panel.
- In side data source panel under wizard we have option of OLAP selector
  wizard & OLAP chart wizard.
- Their you can specify created XML file location.

Comment: I have normal analysis graph not saiku or jpvit how to include these graph

Comment: it will work with OLAP selector wizard & OLAP chart wizard. 
just try.

Comment: If you can go to manage datasource connection in bi server..
import analysis option is their. I just found it.

Comment: ok thanks i will try and than will let you know if i face some problems

Comment: it is not working i want to embed the graph in one pannel it show me to create the whole graph again